# In-application Icons not viewable in ReText under Kubuntu 16.10

Tags: kubuntu, icons

The icons in [ReText](https://github.com/retext-project) are not visible:

[image: picture depicting problem]

Here is how it is supposed to look like:

[image]

I have installed it from the repositories.
Any ideas?

**EDIT** Content of .gtkrc-2.0 as per request in comments

```
include "/usr/share/themes/Breeze/gtk-2.0/gtkrc"
style "user-font"
{
    font_name="Noto Sans Regular"
}
widget_class "*" style "user-font"
gtk-font-name="Noto Sans Regular 10"
gtk-theme-name="Breeze"
gtk-icon-theme-name="breeze"
gtk-fallback-icon-theme="gnome"
gtk-toolbar-style=GTK_TOOLBAR_ICONS
gtk-menu-images=1
gtk-button-images=1
```

Comment: which icon theme were you using?

Comment: @Anwar in KDE I use Breeze Dark, in ReText I have not specified any. The second screenshot is not from my PC.

Comment: What is the content of `.gtkrc-2.0` in your home folder?

Comment: @Anwar Updated my question with the contents of this file. But ReText is indeed a qt application

Comment: @DKBose Yes it is.

Comment: Ok, so after setting the icon set in KDE to Breeze and then resetting it to Breeze Dark, ReText picked up and now it shows the icons.... Thank you for pointing me in the right direction. This question is going to be deleted...

Comment: Bruni have you deleted the .gtkrc file?

Comment: @Bruni instead of deleting this, you can create an answer and accept that one. Maybe some other user will be benefited from it

Comment: @Anwar I did not delete the .gtkrc-2.0 file. Answered my own question. Though if somebody can explain why it worked and add that as a answer, I will happily delete my answer and accept that one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so after setting the icon set in KDE to Breeze and then resetting it to Breeze Dark, ReText picked up and now it shows the icons....

Thank you for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: I use 16.04 and same ReText installed from git project, but icons works perfectly. So, can't tell much why that happened. +1 for solving it yourself